# Single point creation

Tags: arcpy, point, geometry

I am using `arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(pointGeometry, "output")` to create singles points.

Is it possible to create those single points on an existing output without deleting the output before the overwrite?

The method description says:

> The feature class which will be created and to which the features will
>   be copied. If the output feature class already exists and the
>   geoprocessing overwrite option is set to true, the output will be
>   deleted first.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So are you wanting to add to the existing features?  If so, have a look at the [Append tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/data-management-toolbox/append.htm).  It will keep the original features and continue to add to them.  Note that the features should have the same schema.

Comment: If they do not have the same schema just select NO TEST option,  then it will copy over all matching fields to the schema of the feature class you are appending to.

Comment: Right, that also gives you the ability to do any field mapping when you choose `NO TEST`.